# PG::Error: ERROR: out of memory on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I deployed an application on Heroku. I'm using the free service.

Quite frequently, I get the following error.

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  out of memory
```

If I refresh the browser, it's ok. But then, it happens again randomly.

Why does this happen?

Thanks.

Sam Kong

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you experience these when running queries, your queries are complicated or inefficient. The free tier has no cache, so you're already out there.

If you're getting these errors otherwise, open a support ticket at https://help.heroku.com

Answer (score 5):

`heroku restart` simply helped me though

Comment: `restart` would only have an affect here if your connection count was high and consuming too much memory, in which case a restart should clear our all those connections. Heroku Postgres databases are not run on dynos. `restart` does not restart your database instance.

Comment: yes @catsby, in my case I have to run heroku pg:killall and it goes back to normal. it happens regularly these days. any idea how to avoid it ?

Comment: @Emmanuel If you have to regularly restart, or pg:killall, then you may have a connection leak, meaning your application is getting hung / dead connections and simply opening new ones. Each connection needs memory to maintain, and you run out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in a free tier, its maybe because you are using too much memory connecting to PG.

Consider an app running on several dynos, with several processes, each with lots of threads, maybe you are filling up the pool.

Also, as it appears in [Heroku's Help Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#out-of-memory-errors) maybe you are caching too many statements that wont be used.