# Heroku Postgres Out of Memory error

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-postgresql, heroku-postgres

My Rails app has been running fine until this morning.  I tried restarting the app and here is the error i'm getting before i even hit a page.  Out of Memory error on the Postgres connection!  I can connect fine to the database from my dev machine.  I have a Dev account with Heroku Postgres.  I also ran that that SQL statement, and it was fine it should just return 1.

The config var DATABASE_URL is set correctly.

Any ideas?

thx,

matt

```
app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:23827
app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
app[web.1]: Exiting
app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `exec': PG::OutOfMemory: ERROR:  out of memory (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
app[web.1]: DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 96.
app[web.1]: :           SELECT COUNT(*)
app[web.1]:             FROM pg_class c
app[web.1]:             LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
app[web.1]:             WHERE c.relkind in ('v','r')
app[web.1]:             AND c.relname = 'spree_shipments'
app[web.1]:             AND n.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2
```

Comment: When i try to load a page, i get a similar error but on a different database table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PG::Error: ERROR: out of memory on Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621023/pgerror-error-out-of-memory-on-heroku)

Comment: Not really, the answer to that question was "your queries are inefficient".  This is different.  This happens on every single SQL Statement.

Comment: I think it has to do with Forking and the database connection pool: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/forked-pg-connections

Comment: I followed the instructions in the URL above and switched from WEBrick to Unicorn with the recommended configuration.  The problem has **almost** gone away.  It now happens on every 4-5 page loads.  I'd be interested to hear from someone with more Heroku experience.  Is this really b/c postgres needs more memory or an environment issue?

Comment: This sort of thing usually turns out to be load issues on the Heroku VPS being used. Consider failing over via follower promotion to a different server node that might be under less load. It shouldn't happen on a properly configured PostgreSQL with reasonable `work_mem` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Its a little disconcerting.  I'm the only one hitting the database, and its a small db.